# Simplicity is invariant under extension of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

## Problem

Suppose $A$ is a central simple $k$-algebra, which means that the field $k=Z(A)$ and $A$ is itself a simple ring, where $Z(A)$ is the center of $A$, and $K/k$ is a field extension, then $A\otimes_k K$ is a (central) simple $K$-algebra. (Thanks for comments below. I've corrected the statement.)

## Thoughts

It suffices to prove that a nontrivial element, say $\sum_{j=1}^N a_j\otimes \xi_j$ of $A\otimes_k K$ generates the whole algebra, where $\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_N$ are linearly independent over $k$. The problem is that it could be somewhat entangled just like this, so I cannot see any direct way to generate $1\otimes 1$.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: It's not true in general. For example, $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to the direct product of two copies of $\mathbb{C}$, and is not simple.

Comment: On the other hand, if $A$ is required to be *central* simple, then (if I recall correctly) $A\otimes _k K$ is simple.

Comment: @JeremyRickard You're right. I misunderstood the sentence.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, I need to check whether that $A$ is central $k$ implies that $A\otimes_k K$ is central over $K$. I proved this, but I'm not 100% sure. I didn't touch with extension of scalars before.

Comment: @FrankScience I don't know if that's true, but if *both* $A$ and $K$ are central simple algebras, then the tensor product is. The problem is that if $K$ is a strict field extension of $k$, $K$ is never central $k$ simple. It might still hold, though as you stated it.

Comment: @rschwieb Suppose $\sum_k a_k\otimes\xi_k\in Z(A\otimes_k K)$ and $\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_n$ are linearly independent over $k$, and it commutes with any $b\otimes\eta$, then by simple calculation it could be shown that $a_k$ commutes with $b$ for any $b\in A$, thus $a_k\in k$ and thus $\sum_k a_k\otimes\xi_k\in K$.

Comment: @rschwieb Where did you see the statement that if $A$ is central simple then $A\otimes_k K$ is simple? It's stated in Shafarevich's *Basic notions of algebra*, but claimed that it's easy to prove. That book omits many proofs (it's not a textbook but an introduction). I need some reference.

Comment: @FrankScience I think it appears in any basic text on central simple algebras, for example, the second proposition [here](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~len/d70/chap17.pdf)

Comment: @rschwieb Prop 2,(ii) is just a generalization of the problem. Please post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankScience OK: done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there is a theorem on central simple algebras:

> If $A$ is a central simple algebra and $B$ is a simple $k$ algebra, then $A\otimes_k B$ is a simple $k$ algebra.

A proof appears [in these notes](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~len/d70/chap17.pdf), for example.